# Can I start work at another company, while being on leave from another company?

Tags: new-job, employment

I am about to move from one job to another. I have my holidays saved for the whole year in the first company. Based on that, I talked with the first company that I will be taking the whole month of Oct as leave. But on the other hand the next company is eager for me to join them, as soon as possible. So here are my questions:

- Is it possible that I join 1st Oct itself, while being on leave from the first company? So basically I will be getting salary from both positions for Oct?
- Will I be in trouble for this?
- Should I wait till Nov?

Comment: Very much location-specific but find out the implications of working for two companies for the month, tax-wise. You should tag with your country...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to speak to your current company's HR department, this might breach certain clauses in your contract, like confidentiality, if they are in the same sector.

Other considerations are that you'll be taxed as if having two jobs during the period, which could hurt you more in the short run.

As long as your current company's HR department say it's OK, then there should be no issue, assuming there is no local law preventing you from doing this. You can spend your holiday how you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems, depending on your location, and on your contract.

First, your contract with the old company may not allow you to take another job while you are still working for the old company. Or only if you get written permission. In the second case, get written permission.

Second, there are countries where you don't only have the *right* to annual holiday, you actually *must* take annual holiday. Meaning you are required to not work for a certain number of days a year. The new company may be breaking the law if you don't have so many days off work in a year.